# How to write a non-blocking, delayed for loop in JavaScript without recursion?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, promise

I want a for-loop that executes its code every X amount of milliseconds. It should be non-recursive to avoid a stack overflow after many iterations. Also, it should be non-blocking, and its performance should be decent.

I tried it with a promise:

```js
(async () => {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
    await new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("run number", i);
        res();
      }, 100);
    });
  }
})();
```

But the first execution is **after** the duration passed to setTimeout, not once before like in a real for-loop.

Comment: Move your logic to before the `await`?

Comment: Why would `setInterval()` not work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have to pull the function that does whatever work you want to do out of the loop. Then you can call it *before* the loop starts for the first iteration, and then after the timed intervals thereafter.

```js
(async () => {
  function doWork(iteration, finish) {
    console.log(`run number ${iteration}`);
    finish();
  }

  doWork(0, _ => _);
  for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    await new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        doWork(i, res);
      }, 100);
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: The Promise initializer function doesn't really have to be `async`.

Comment: …and you should never do work from a `setTimeout` callback in promise code, as the `setTimeout` cannot handle exceptions

Comment: @Bergi oh yea good point, I was sticking to the original pattern. Honestly the OP's solution is probably better :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it. Here my solution:

```js
(async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
    console.log("run number", i);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
  }
})();
```

Comment: yea this is also fine.